# not able to add google calendar in elementary calendar

Tags: calendar

not able to add google calendar in elementary calendar
Sign-in attempt was blocked
    xxxxxxxxxxx@thehiring.agency
Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your account from a non-Google app. Google blocked them, but you should check what happened. Review your account activity to make sure that no one else has access.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The right answer depends on if you use **2-factor authentication** (2FA) or not.

### With 2FA

You have to create a **per-app password** in your Google account [here](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords). Afterwords you will be able to login using that single-use password with your account.

### Without 2FA

In this case I think you have to tell Google to **trust less-secure apps** in your Google account [settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) (it just means they use standard authentication methods instead of Google-made methods). I cannot confirm this works as I no longer have any account without 2FA.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option into your google account to enable access for non secure apps, or something like that. Usually by default it is set to disable access and this is the reason the Calendar app cannot connect. You have to change it in order to get access

Comment: You don't *have to* change it, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is no working for me either. 
Also the webDAV API is not working for external calendars.

I installed minetime which is fitting the design quite well and you have also some additional handy features.